# Android several MediaPlayers

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I want to show 4 views which will be streaming video from server. I created 4 views which are streaming video and I tested it on Nexus 7(2013), it's work fine. But when I tested on another device (Samsung Tab2) videos freezes after several minutes and some videos don't even start. It happens because MediaPlayer receives Error (100,0). I tried restart MediaPlayer when MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener receives this error, but after restarting I receive same error. This problem I have even with 2 MediaPlayers, but if I have only one MediaPlayer it's work perfect. As I understood my samsung can't work normally with more than one MediaPlayer. How can I figure out how much mediaplayers will work fine with some device? Or maybe someone faces off the same problem and can help me

Answer (score 3):

It is look like Android issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17802 You could try to use other player like [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)